# Почему вывод массива String выводит адрес?

Tags: c++

Либо **я криворукий** либо я чего-то не понимаю)

Перезапуск проги лишь меняет адрес массива

**Код**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    string classmates[3] = { "Козлов", "Иванов", "Сидоров" };
    cout << classmates << endl; //Вывожу весь массив, а выводится адрес?;
    cout << classmates[0] << endl; //Вывожу микрочелика
    cin.get();
}
```

**Первый вывод**

```
0040FE2C
Козлов
```

**Второй вывод**

```
004FFA1C
Козлов
```

и т.п.

Если допустим вывести весь массив символов ТО ОН ВЫВОДИТ ВЕСЬ МАССИВ СИМВОЛОВ.
Объясните мне почему так происходит и можно ли исправить эту ошибку? Ну или хотя бы как-то обойти, а то не удобно как-то поочередно все строчки выводить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что просто `classmates` низводится при передаче в функцию вывода (`operator<<`) до обычного указателя на первый элемент массива, и выводится как указатель - поскольку не является указателем на `char`.

В массиве лежат три объекта типа `string`, каждый из которых где-то внутри содержит указатель на реальную строку с фамилией... И как вы предлагаете выводить их все три? Если обратиться к ним нужно через 2 уровня косвенности? Они же лежат в совершенно разных местах памяти...

Да и что вы хотите получить?

```
КозловИвановСидоров
```

?

Нет, конечно, если вы считаете, что

```
for(auto s: classmates) cout << s << endl;
```

неудобно - можно воспользоваться стандартными алгоритмами и итераторами:

```
copy(begin(classmates),end(classmates),ostream_iterator<string>(cout,"\n"));
```

Comment: Откуда взялся Козлов? Должно быть: ИвановПетровСидоров - три брата.

Comment: @Harry да хотя бы так хочу получить, но увы то что вы описали я не смог понять ибо еще скрипткидди, можешь объяснить понятным для рачелы языком?

Comment: @Learpcs Эээ... Нет, не могу, потому что не знаю, что такое *скрипткидди* и *рачелы*... Простите, воспитан советской школой :(

Comment: @Igor Это не братья, а однофамильцы...

Comment: @Harry ScriptKiddie - Малыш в кодинге, рачела - человек с руками растущими из задницы и с клешнями вместо рук

Comment: @Harry увы такой молодежный сленг, надо адаптироваться)

Comment: Ну я примерно так и объяснил. Что вывести их все вместе невозможно хотя бы потому, что эти строки могут лежать в совершенно разных местах памяти. Стандарт языка не предусматривает такие фокусы. Но позволяет написать свой оператор вывода, если очень хочется - но это уже совсем другой вопрос...

Comment: Аааааа допер, спасибо)), твою помощь страна не забудет

Answer (score 1):

classmates - это массив. operator<< в ostream для массива не перегружен. Но массив без труда преобразуется в указатель, а operator<< перегружен для указателей, поэтому будет срабатывать перегрузка для указателя. При передаче operator<< указателя, он выводит значение указателя, т.е. адрес (для указателей на char будет выводить C-строку, но у нас не char).

Можно определить свой operator<<, чтобы выводить массивы:

```
template<std::size_t N>
std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream &stream, const std::string (&arr)[N]) 
{
    for (auto &str: arr) {
        stream << str << '\n';
    }
    return stream;
}
```

Теперь при выводе массива будет выведена каждая строка отдельно.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


template<std::size_t N>
std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream &stream, const std::string (&arr)[N]) 
{
    for (auto &str: arr) {
        stream << str << '\n';
    }
    return stream;
}


int main()
{
    std::string classmates[3] = { "Козлов", "Иванов", "Сидоров" };
    std::cout << classmates << std::endl;
}
```

http://rextester.com/SSFBE17244

Comment: @Learpcs алгоритм? )))

Comment: человек нестыдится спрашивать - это уже похвально, и не нужно забывать, что каждый когда то начинал учиться и  знания на этом этапе были не на высоком уровне...

Comment: Я к тому, что весь алгоритм здесь - последовательный перебор элементов массива. :)